# Cannot read NDEF file using Android HCE and PN532 nfc

Tags: android, hce, pn532

I am currently running android_hce code for arduino attached with PN532 NFC Hat to send Command APDUs to my android APP. APP is running in HCE mode. I want to read the NDEF File/data from the Android App using the arduino.
Ndefdata I am trying to send is a String "github.com/AndroidCrypto?tab=repositories"

Sequence of Command APDUs I am sending

```
complete sequence:
commandApdu: 00a4040007d276000085010100
responseApdu: 9000
commandApdu: 00a4000c02e103
responseApdu: 9000
commandApdu: 00b000000f
responseApdu: 000f20003b00340406e10400ff00ff9000
commandApdu: 00a4000c02e104
responseApdu: 9000
commandApdu: 00b0000002
responseApdu: 00309000
commandApdu: 00b000022e
responseApdu: Error
```

The error is because of the following part. (debugged)

```
    PN532::inDataExchange(uint8_t *send, uint8_t sendLength, uint8_t *response, uint8_t *responseLength)
    .
    .
    .
    int16_t status = HAL(readResponse)(response, *responseLength, 1000);
    if (status < 0) {
        return false;
    }
```

Arduino code snippet for the last C-APDU

```
uint8_t fapdu[] = {0x00,
                          0xb0,
                          0x00,
                          0x02,
                          0x2e};  
                          
        uint8_t fback[64];
        uint8_t flength = 64; 
        success = nfc.inDataExchange(fapdu, sizeof(fapdu), fback, &flength);
        
        
        if(success) {
         
          Serial.print("responseLengthfinal Read: "); Serial.println(flength);
           
          nfc.PrintHexChar(fback, flength);
        }
        else {
          
          Serial.println("Broken connection?"); 
        }
```

However, the Android Log shows the correct response

```
commandApdu: 00a4040007d276000085010100
 responseApdu: 9000
commandApdu: 00a4000c02e103
responseApdu: 9000
commandApdu: 00b000000f
 responseApdu: 000f20003b00340406e10400ff00ff9000
 commandApdu: 00a4000c02e104
 responseApdu: 9000
commandApdu: 00b0000002
 file length: 50
responseApdu: 00309000
commandApdu: 00b000022e
 file length: 50
responseApdu: d1012c5402656e6769746875622e636f6d2f416e64726f696443727970746f3f7461623d7265706f7369746f72699000
```

Android app is implemented using [Link](https://github.com/MichaelsPlayground/NfcHceNdefEmulator).

I am not sure why the arduino code cannot read the response APDU for the final command.

However when I use the following APDU in the final case

```
uint8_t fapdu[] = {0x00,
                   0xb0,
                   0x00,
                   0x02,
                   0x14};


responseLengthfinal Read: 22
22:22:47.857 ->  D1 01 2C 54 02 65 6E 67 69 74 68 75 62 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 41 6E 90 00    ..,T.engithub.com/An..
```

But when I use (23 Read Length)

```
uint8_t fapdu[] = {0x00,
                   0xb0,
                   0x00,
                   0x02,
                   0x15};

Error in inDataExchange process of nfc.
```